# Python Countdown Timer Issue

Tags: python, timer, countdown

I'm having trouble getting this countdown timer to work. The 2 print statements within the while loop print on the same line and it's too fast to see most of the time. P.S. I'm kind of new to Python so excuse me if I don't understand everything. Thanks!

```
import time
import datetime
eh = datetime.datetime(2019,3,31,20,30)
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print("Earth Hour!: " + eh.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
tte = eh - now
while eh > now:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("Current Time: " + now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), end="\r")
    print("Time Till Earth Hour: " + str(tte), end = "\r")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a \r for both print statements, effectively letting the one override the other. Furthermore in the while loop you want to continuously adjust the time. Here is a small adjustment i made. Perhaps you can add your second statement in there yourself now.

```
import time
import datetime
eh = datetime.datetime(2019,3,31,20,30)
print("Earth Hour!: " + eh.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
now = datetime.datetime.now()


while eh > now:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    tte = eh - now
    print("Time Till Earth Hour: " + str(tte), end = "\r")
```

Comment: The person trying to edit my post, your answer does not create a 'timer'. The now has to be recalculated every loop...

Comment: Thanks for the help! I still have a small issue though. The time till earth hour+ str(tte) portion seems to be flickering. It disappears then reappears. How do I get this to stop?

Comment: for me this works perfectly. I tested it. No flickering and you see the time count down fine...

Comment: I think it was a problem with my IDE. It works when I run it elsewhere. Thanks!